# Unable to open the Kibana dashboard

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I just installed the kiban (`docker pull docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.0.1`) as docker image and I used below command to run the image service on linux.

```
  docker run -d -p 5061:5061 --name kibana <ImageName>
```

And it's make the service to up and running, and I just opened the browser and hit the Kibana service but it shows below error message:

> *Login is currently disabled. Administrators should consult the Kibana logs for more details.*

[image]
I just googled and observed that I need to make some changes on kibana.yaml file but not sure where I can find that file.

I used find command to search the folder or file but I didn't find any.

**Search:**

```
find kibana
```

**Output:**

`No matches found`.

**Kibana Logs:**

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-21T18:18:46Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-21T18:18:49Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: where your elasticsearch live?

Comment: kibana file in container  is in /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml  Could you please post also the error before No living connections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may disable `xpack.security.enabled` , so try to run your `container` like this:

```
docker run -d -p 5061:5061 -e  "XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false" --name kibana <IMAGE>
```

Comment: I just ran the above command and observed below in log {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-22T06:07:32Z","tags":["info","optimize"],"pid":1,"message":"Optimizing and caching bundles for graph, monitoring, ml, kibana, stateSessionStorageRedirect, timelion, dashboardViewer and status_page. This may take a few minutes"}

Answer (score 2):

This error can happens if the Elasticsearch has the license expired.

If you have the Kibana configured do connect in a Elasticsearch URL, like (Docker example):

```
 kibana:
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.0.0
   container_name: kibana_ms
   environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

The expected error on the Elasticsearch is something about license expired, that prevents third tools to access the monitor data from Elasticsearch:

```
elasticsearch_ms | [2020-05-21T15:05:29,911][ERROR][o.e.x.s.a.f.SecurityActionFilter] [wcr8rMd] blocking [cluster:monitor/stats] operation due to expired license. Cluster health, cluster stats and indices stats 
elasticsearch_ms | operations are blocked on license expiration. All data operations (read and write) continue to work. 
elasticsearch_ms | If you have a new license, please update it. Otherwise, please reach out to your support contact
```

This prevents Kibana to connect on Elasticsearch and this (somehow) makes Kibana asking for login to access the Dashboard. You can find similar error, on the same scenario, trying to make another Web Admin Tools (like [Cerebro](https://hub.docker.com/r/dylanmei/cerebro/), that returns 403).

## Solution

You can disable de `XPACK`:

```
xpack.security.enabled=false
```

On Docker, you can do:

```
 elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.0.0
   container_name: elasticsearch_ms
   environment:
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please revisit your IPv4 address, might be your IPv4 is changed and it can cause this issue.

```
docker run -p 5601:5601 -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://[IP where elasticsearch is running]:9200 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2
```